# How to send message to new user after user comment on a post

Tags: facebook-messenger

I need to send an invitation message to user after the user comments on a post in a facebook page.

The steps are as below:

1. User comments on a post
2. The app get notified of the comment through webhook
3. Get the psid from the comment
4. Send invitation message to the psid through messenger using

> messaging_type = MESSAGE_TAG and tag = NON_PROMOTIONAL_SUBSCRIPTION

The above flow works if the user has ever interact with the page through messenger before.

But if the user has not interact with the page through messenger before, the send message API fails with response below:

> {"error":{"message":"(#551) This person isn't available right
>   now.","type":"OAuthException","code":551,"error_subcode":1545041,"fbtrace_id":"....."}}

Tried using some other apps, such as Many Chat. It works for new users in the above scenario.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

The test is as below:

```sh
curl -X POST -d @test_message.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/me/messages?access_token=<page token>'

test_message.json:
{
  "messaging_type": "MESSAGE_TAG",
  "tag": "NON_PROMOTIONAL_SUBSCRIPTION",
  "recipient": {
    "id": "<psid of the user>"
  },
  "message": {
    "text": "This is a test"
  }
}
```

Expect the message send is successful.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out. The following API should be used to send message to user who made a facebook comment:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/object/private_replies